# Install Gnome Chemistry Utils via ppa

Tags: command-line

Hello i was searching for chemistry apps for linux and i found this Gnome Chemistry Utils, but i dont know how to install it, there a launchpad from ubuntu to use it, but i dont know how to make the termial commands to install it.

This is the launchpad: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-chemistry-utils

Comment: You do NOT need to use a PPA. Gnome Chemistry Utils is in the Ubuntu Repositories.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A great time to learn how to use apt!

**Lesson 1**: Let's use apt to find out which available packages have "gnome" and "chemistry" in their title or description.

```
$ apt search gnome chemistry

Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
gcrystal/cosmic 0.14.17-1ubuntu2 amd64
  lightweight crystal structures visualizer

gcu-bin/cosmic 0.14.17-1ubuntu2 amd64
  GNOME chemistry utils (helper applications)

gcu-plugin/cosmic 0.14.17-1ubuntu2 amd64
  GNOME chemistry utils (browser plugin)

ghemical/cosmic 3.0.0-3build1 amd64
  GNOME molecular modelling environment

libgcu0v5/cosmic 0.14.17-1ubuntu2 amd64
  GNOME chemistry utils (library)
```

**Lesson 2**: Let's use apt to find more information about the `gcu-bin` package:

```
$ apt show gcu-bin

[additional information has been edited out for clarity]

Description: GNOME chemistry utils (helper applications)
 The GNOME Chemistry Utils provide C++ classes and Gtk+-2 widgets
 related to chemistry. They will be used in future versions of both
 gcrystal and gchempaint.
 .
 This package provides 4 applications:
 .
  * a molecular structures viewer (GChem3D)
  * a molar mass calculator (GChemCalc)
  * a periodic table of the elements (GChemTable)
  * a spectra viewer (GSpectrum)
```

**Lesson 3**: How to install a package. Let's keep using the `gcu-bin` package as an example.

```
$ sudo apt install gcu-bin
```